# JavaScript function "not defined" after importing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" />

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function testFunction() {
                alert('It works');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="test.html" onsubmit="testFunction()">
            <input type="submit" value="Test" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My `testFunction()` function works fine by it self, that is until I import jQuery with the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" />
```

Now it fails and tells me that
**Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined**

I am hoping this is a newbie mistake and that I am missing something obvious. Notice that I haven't even try to use jQuery yet.

Comment: Just close your script tag...!

Comment: hey man there is no need of writing language="javascript" because type already specifies it!

Comment: I don't think I ever got som many answers so quickly before :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close the `<script>` tag fully.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Works great on jsfiddle after changing:
http://jsfiddle.net/PVYM9/

Also, in HTML5 you can shorten the doctype to just `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and you don't need to define `type` properties for your `<script>` tags. See jsfiddle for example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the script tag in the right way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

(note the closing `</script>` tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> // close the script tag properly

        <script type="text/javascript"> // there is no need of writing language="javascript"
            function testFunction() {
                alert('It works');
            }
        </script>
```

hey man there is no need of writing language="javascript" because type already specifies it!

Answer (score 1):

Despite being valid XML, many HTML elements (such as `script`, `textarea` etc) don't work well in most browsers if you close them using a trailing slash (i.e. `<element />`). You need to create open and close tags for them to work (`<element></element>`). That seems to be true for XHTML as well.

Others, like your `input` tag, work fine the way it is. I don't know why some require a closing tag and others not, neither a list of those elements, I just know some of them from experience...

Comment: It never occurred to me that this might be the issue, although now that you mention it I do remember having the same problem with a `textarea` tag a long time ago.